# an error in relative root mean square error as a custom loss function in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras

i'm implementing relative root mean square error in keras as a custom loss function
here is my code:

```
def relative_root_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
   return (K.sqrt((K.mean(K.square((y_pred - y_true)))/ n)) / ((K.mean(y_true)) / n) * 100)
```

then i used this loss function in model compile as follows:

```
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = relative_root_mean_squared_error, 
          metrics =["accuracy"])
```

after that I'm trying to fit my model with this code :

```
model_history = model.fit(
    x=[l_train, s_train,w_train], y=y_train,
    validation_data=([l_test, s_test , w_test], y_predict),
    epochs=500, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
```

but it gives me an error which is :

```
TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type uint8 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'
```

how can i fix this issue?

Comment: what are the types of `y_true` and `y_pred`? I expect one of them will be `uint8` and the other `float32`

Comment: @Anwarvic  i don't know what is the type of y_true but y_pred is uint8

Comment: Try casting `y_pred` to be `float32` using `tf.cast` like so: `tf.cast(y_pred, tf.int32)`

Comment: Why is y_pred a uint8? it should be a float, a neural network produced floats, what is the model you are using here?